# error C2509: member function not declared in derived class

Tags: c++, compiler-errors

I have base class **State** and derived class **InitialState**.When i build solution compiler show error C2509: *'setView': member function not declared in 'InitialState'* and I don't know why...
Here is **State.h :**

```
#ifndef STATE_H
#define STATE_H
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

class State {
public:
    State() { isPrototype = true; }
    virtual void execute() = 0;
    virtual void setView(ostream& screen) const = 0;
    virtual void onEnter() { system("CLS"); setView(cout); }
    virtual void onExit() = 0;

private:
    bool isPrototype;
    State* nextState;
};


#endif
```

**InitialState.h :**

```
#ifndef INITIAL_STATE_H
#define INITIAL_STATE_H

#include"State.h"

class InitialState : public State {
public:
    void execute() {}
    void onExit() {}
    void setView(ostream& screen) const;
};

#endif
```

and **InitialState.cpp:**

```
#include"InitialState.h"

void InitialState::setView(ostream& screen) const {
    screen << "Welcome!" << endl;
    screen << "Please select what you want to do: " << endl << "1.Load card" << endl << "0.Exit" << endl;
}
```

I have tried to add key word "virtual" in the front of functions in InitialState.h , but it doesn't change anything...also when I delete InitialState.cpp the code compiles normaly.

Here is the **AtmTest.cpp:**

```
#include "PaymentCard.h"
//#include "Atm.h"

int main() {
    return 0;
}
```

but it has nothing with State...
and here are the other classes:
**Atm.h:**

```
#ifndef ATM_H
#define ATM_H
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

class Atm {
public:
    static Atm* get();
    static void release() { delete instance; instance = nullptr; }  //Singleton
private:
    int serialNumber;
    string bankName;
    string location;

    //Singleton:
    Atm();
    static Atm* instance;
    Atm(const Atm& m) = delete;
    Atm& operator=(const Atm& m) = delete;
    Atm(Atm&&) = delete;
    Atm& operator=(Atm&& m) = delete;

};

#endif
```

**Atm.cpp:**

```
#include"Atm.h"

//Singleton:
Atm* Atm::instance = nullptr;


Atm* Atm::get() {
    if (instance == nullptr) {
        instance = new Atm();
    }
    return instance;
}
```

**PaymentCard.h:**

```
#ifndef PAYMENT_CARD_H
#define PAYMENT_CARD_H
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

class PaymentCard {
public:
    PaymentCard(string clientName);
    void addMoney(unsigned int amount) { currentAmount += amount; }
    void withdrawMoney(int amount);
    friend ostream& operator<< (ostream&, const PaymentCard&);
private:
    static int NumberGenerator;     
    unsigned int serialNumber;      
    string clientName;
    int currentAmount;
};


#endif
```

**PaymentCard.cpp:**

```
#include"PaymentCard.h"

int PaymentCard::NumberGenerator = 0;

PaymentCard::PaymentCard(string clientName) {
    currentAmount = 0;
    this->clientName = clientName;
    serialNumber = NumberGenerator++;
}

void PaymentCard::withdrawMoney(int amount) {
    if (amount > currentAmount)cout << "Ovde ide izuzetak";
    else currentAmount -= amount;
}

ostream& operator<< (ostream &os, const PaymentCard& card){
    os << card.serialNumber + 1 << ". Client: " << card.clientName << endl;
    return os;
}
```

This code is not near the finish, but it worked until i have made SetView in InitialState, so idk what happened..

Comment: Tip: Don't place `using namespace` statements in header files. Bad mojo.

Comment: Post the code that calls the function.

Comment: [The code you show compiles fine](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ca78d2b408cb7b08).  There is probably a problem in code that you are not showing us.

Comment: I didn't called function yet, in the main i have just this: return 0;..

Comment: @IgorBeracka Where is `main()` located? You should show us the code.

Comment: @DrewDormann I have other classes but they have compiled fine, and they are not using class State or InitialState yet..

Comment: @RawN i have posted all the code..

Comment: @IgorBeracka Try to squeeze it into a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Minimal being the keyword.

Comment: and remove `using namespace std;` from header files, and add the keyword `override` after the declaration of `setView` in `InitialState.h` : `void setView(ostream& screen) const override;`. These will help narrowing the problem for the guys trying to help.

Comment: Identify the line that causes the error.

Comment: @latedeveloper here is the error in line 6 of InitialState.cpp:                                          d:\documents\visual studio 2015\projects\atmtest\atm\initialstate.cpp(6): error C2509: 'setView': member function not declared in 'InitialState'
1>  d:\documents\visual studio 2015\projects\atmtest\atm\initialstate.h(6): note: see declaration of 'InitialState'

Comment: @A.S.H why i have to remove using namespace std?

Comment: @latedeveloper I guess it is when compiling `InitialState.cpp` the method `setView` when attempting to define seems like undeclared for the compiler

Comment: @IgorBeracka it is considered bad practice and source for trouble in header files, and even in source files for the pros.

Comment: @A.S.H i have tried with override, but the same error is showing

Comment: @IgorBeracka Yes I know, but I was asking for some first steps in the right direction.

Comment: @IgorBeracka would you do me a favor? just for checking: replace all those `ostream&` with `std::ostream&`? Do it in all files of State and InitialState (.h and .cpp)

Comment: @A.S.H i have done that and again it shows the same error, I have started a new project and i am adding a functions one by one to see what causes the problem..also i didn't mentioned that i have make all these files in one static library file and AtmTest in executable file..i have refferenced it and included the Static library in the exe file..

Comment: I have created new project and copied function by function and it works now..wtf :/

Comment: http://oop.etf.rs/domaci/2016-2017/dz3/OOP_DZ3_v1.pdf :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem: InitialState.h is precompiled, and you are linking to a prior version of InitialState.h. Clean, rebuild, and/or disable precompiled headers altogether.

I suspect that, because:

1. I can reproduce the error by commenting out the declaration of setView() in InitialState.h
2. The resulting error message refers to line 3 of InitialState.cpp and the error message you posted refers to line 6, which indicates that the posted source code did not produce that error message.

To reproduce the error, one has to comment out the setView() decalration from the InitialState class:

```
class InitialState : public State {
public:
    void execute() {}
    void onExit() {}
    //void setView(ostream& screen) const;
};
```

Then one gets the following error message:

```
1>InitialState.cpp(3): error C2509: 'setView' : member function not declared in 'InitialState'
1>          c:\users\laci\desktop\samples\stackoverflow\InitialState.h(6) : see declaration of 'InitialState'
```